# Looking for 80's scifi comic about astronaut looking for Earth in ancient alien spaceship

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, comics, hyperspace

I have been looking for a long while for the name of an 80's comic/graphic novel of which I once read a short section as a child. What I can remember is this:

The story is about an astronaut who tries to return to Earth and somehow gets aboard a very old ancient alien spaceship. The spaceship has an onboard AI which agrees to help the astronaut to look for Earth and get him home.

A while later they arrive at Earth and it is shown on the monitor but the AI says it does not match it's records for Earth so it restarts the engines to continue the search. The astronaut protests but to no avail. Then the astronaut realizes the ship (and AI) must be really, really old and probably has quite ancient and outdated specs on Earth in it's data banks.

So the ship goes back into hyperspace and while in hyperspace a mine or something attaches itself to the spaceship and it's stuck there. So the astronaut has to get outside to try and pry it off the ship with a rod or crowbar. While doing so he feels the effects of hyperspace slowly dissolving/disintegrating his suit and his body. So time is of the essence.

And that's all I can remember. I never got the read the rest. Some other details:

- The comic was in Dutch but I am sure it was just a translated comic
- The astronaut called the ship "Ship" (or "Schip" in Dutch)
- The ship was kinda acorn shaped with multiple engines at the rear in a circular arrangement
- Hyperspace was drawn like a thick misty medium
- The drawing style was not overly detailed, probably black and white or low color use
- The story was probably bundled with some other short scifi stories

So any idea's? I personally think it's a French short story or something but I am not sure.

Update: Someone anonymous tried to add the following text (was too long for a comment):

*Edit. I am also looking for this story. Additional information. The ship takes the astronaut through hyperspace to a busy civilisation. It turns out that his ship is really old, and worth a fortune to collectors.
Obviously there is lots of room for plot development, but I believe that is where the comic ended at that time.
I am pretty sure the comic was in color. When the ship is ready to take off, it claims it is without error, but the astronaut sees tell-tale red warning lights in a sea of green control lights.
It wasn't Marvell. There were no superheroes. The ship wasn't some magical supermind caught in a ship either. It is very advanced to Earth standards, but it has developed errors over time and it isn't flawless. In the place where it came from, it is a relic, an artefact, a collectable.
It could have been French originally as lots of comics came from Belgium or France.*

Dear Anonymous, thank you for your addition, it does help me a little and even tells me some more of the story. But the search continues. Please sign up an account so we can talk about it more.

Comment: Unlikely to be a match, but in his stories from the 1970s and 1980, Marvel's Starlord had a ship named Ship. The story you describe doesn't ring any immediate bells, but I haven't read most of the Starlord stories from that era since they came out.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. Looked it up and I think you mean http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ship_(Rora)/Gallery?file=Marvel_Spotlight_Vol_2_7_001.jpg. But that's not a match unfortunately

Comment: That's her! I didn't think it would match, but it seemed unusual enough to mention, just in case.